# Count 3 values in single column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions

I have a column values are from 0, 1, 2 see below

```
0 = no, 1 = yes and 2 is waiting
```

I just want to show the count of yes no and waiting where `adminid=1468`

```
 IsVerified        AdminId
    0               1468
    0               1475  
    1               1468 
    1               1468
    1               1468 
    1               1468 
    1               1475
    2               1468
    2               1466
```

I want to display this as where `adminid=1468`

```
No    Yes    Waiting   AdminId
1      4       1        1468
```

So far I have used

```
SELECT     
    COUNT(s.IsVerified) AS [Yes]
    ,COUNT(s.IsVerified) AS [No]
    ,COUNT(s.IsVerified) AS [Waiting]
    ,g.AdminId
FROM    
    tbl_Squad s, tbl_Match m, tbl_Group g
WHERE   
    m.GroupId = g.GroupId          
    --AND g.AdminId=@AdminId
    AND g.AdminId=1468          
GROUP BY         
    s.IsVerified
```

but it gives three rows while I want only one row where I'm wrong

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select sum(case when s.isverified = 0 then 1 else 0 end) no
, sum(case when s.isverified = 1 then 1 else 0 end) yes
, sum(case when s.isverified = 2 then 1 else 0 end) waiting

from tbl_squad s join tbl_group g on s.groupid = g.groupid

where g.adminid = 1468
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUM(case when s.IsVerified= 0 then 1 else 0 end) as No
, SUM(case when s.IsVerified= 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Yes
, SUM(case when s.IsVerified= 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Waiting
,g.AdminId

from tbl_Squad s join tbl_Group g on s.GroupId = g.GroupId

where --g.adminId=@AdminId
      g.AdminId= 1468
group by g.AdminId
```